# Android Studio update to 1.0 fails

Tags: android, android-studio, auto-update

I was updating my Android Studio to 1.0. I went through the process of automatic update it was a patch file of around 8 MB.
System downloaded it and when applying the update, it failed and shown the below screen shot. For information I am using windows 7.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your current installation is somewhat corrupted.

Delete the entire contents of the Android Studio installation folder, download the latest version from [this page](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest), and unzip it into the exact same directory.

You will not lose any settings or preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trashing the installation, I killed all java processes and re-tried the upgrade to 1.0. Worked for me. I think the problem was in upgrading to 0.99 and then 1.0 on it's heels.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened before when I was trying to update both Android Studio and Intellij.

I deleted all the contents in the installation folder and still doesn't work. I ended up reinstalling java SDK and it worked for me. Hope it helps!